Enter key "stuck" after opening application after 24.04
When opening a new program such as Firefox Ubuntu keeps spamming the Enter key.
For example, if I am in Visual Studio Code, about 100 new lines are created.
I haven't experienced this issue before. I am using Ubuntu 24.04, Lenovo Yoga s730. This is bugging me daily. I added an animation to show the issue:


Try disabling the keyboard, it doesn't seem like a software bug. Make sure you don't have a program like Autoclicker enabled.

Can you try running Ubuntu from a live USB and check if the issue is present there? If so, it must be a hardware issue.

Thanks for the suggestions, I might try that later. Not sure how to disable the keyboard but i did try another language of the keyboard. Still the same issue.

This is no longer an issue. Must have been fixed automatically with some update.

This is most likely a hardware issue and not an Ubuntu problem.
I once had a similar problem in my desktop's keyboard, it was continously producing full-stops.
Such issues happen because moisture and dirt accumulate inside the keyboard, and create mini short-circuits, which closes the circuit below the specific key(s) you have issue with.
The solution is to clean the keyboard with a hair drier or vacuum cleaner (from outside), and if possible, open the keyboard and clean it. Also, if you live in tropical regions, keeping the keyboard under the sun for several hours might get rid of the moisture and fix the issue.

Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try cleaning later and report back. I'm a bit interested in why it should be a hardware problem - It's only triggered when opening a new program? I've newer experienced "enter-key-stuck-effect" in other scenarios

Hmm, that's interesting. Can you replicate this in a live USB session?

I noticed this as soon as I installed 24.04 too so unsure how dirt decided to specifically time its land on my keyboard at exactly the same time after installation.
